# RabbitMQ : add exception to message header before send to DLQ with DLX policy

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Can you please suggest a way to add the exception to my original message header before sending it to DLQ with DLX policy in RabbitMQ

i tried to do it with aspect but my altered message is not the one pushed to DLQ, which is normal, the original message in the broker is always published instead.

```
@Service
@RabbitListener(queues = "queueName")
public class Listener {


    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(BasicMessage message) {
        try {
            doSomeWork();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message has to be republished programmatically; you can't modify the message if the broker just re-routes it to the DLQ.

The framework provides a mechanism to do this.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners).

> The `RepublishMessageRecoverer` publishes the message with additional information in message headers, such as the exception message, stack trace, original exchange, and routing key. Additional headers can be added by creating a subclass and overriding `additionalHeaders()`. The `deliveryMode` (or any other properties) can also be changed in the `additionalHeaders()`.

Comment: thanks Gary, i know about the recoverer, i will recheck again how to do it in a clean maner. even if i consider shifting this critical traitement toward the microservice too risky, in case of crash, the message will be  lost

Comment: I just opened this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1293 - it should be easier to wait for a publisher confirm after a republish. Currently you'd have to subclass the template to do that.

Comment: @GaryRussell how do you find making RepublishMessageRecoverer.prefixedOriginalRoutingKey protected instead of private?

RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer would be fine, but I can't add custom headers there. RepublishMessageRecoverer is good for headers, but it sends back to wrong exchange - I would like to make it behave the same as RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer about used DLQ/exchange.
 If prefixedOriginalRoutingKey() was protected, it would be sufficient to override it without necessity of copy-paste recover() and other private methods used by it.

Comment: Feel free to open a new feature issue on GitHub, but making that method protected won't change the exchange - you can set the `errorExchangeName` for that (also `errorRoutingKey` and then the prefix won't be used).